# Cannot access JBoss admin console

Tags: centos, jboss7.x, application-server

I am trying to access a jboss-as-7.1.1-Final admin console, but when I try to reach for the address: ip_address:9991 (I changed the port from 9990 to 9991) the browser seems it cannot move on from the loading spinner:
[jboss admin console spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsOD5.png)
I already edited the standalone.xml file to allow any IP to reach the interface (so it is not limited to 127.0.0.1) and I disabled iptables to prevent any possible issue.
I have no problems reaching the deployed web applications or the server welcome-page on the 8080 port.

```
12:45:20,721 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011942: 
Stopping OSGi Framework  
12:45:20,732 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/] has not been started  
12:45:38,335 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem  
12:45:38,379 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.  
12:45:38,419 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem  
12:45:38,423 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem  
12:45:38,461 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)  
12:45:38,480 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem  
12:45:38,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final  
12:45:38,573 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension  
12:45:38,648 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service  
12:45:38,677 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]  
12:45:38,758 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)  
12:45:39,148 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA  
12:45:39,230 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-5) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--0.0.0.0-8080  
12:45:39,467 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments  
12:45:39,485 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on /0.0.0.0:9999  
12:45:39,485 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on /0.0.0.0:4447  
12:45:39,626 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]  

-- Deployment info cut --  

12:45:54,326 INFO  [net.fckeditor.connector.ConnectorServlet] (MSC service thread 1-7) ConnectorServlet successfully initialized!  
12:45:54,471 INFO  [net.fckeditor.connector.ConnectorServlet] (MSC service thread 1-5) ConnectorServlet successfully initialized!  

-- Deployment info cut --  

12:45:57,994 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9991  
12:45:57,995 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 21387ms - Started 999 of 1078 services (78 services are passive or on-demand)
```

JBoss is running (as a service) on a CentOS7 x64 server.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Given the image it looks like the console is being reached, just not displayed. Do you have some kind of script blocking plugin?

Comment: I don't think so. I tried with different browers (Chrome, Opera, Firefox, IE11 and Edge), even in their anonymous/incognito mode, precisely to prevent any interference from the extensions.

Comment: I'm not too sure what the issue could be. The console should all be in JavaScript and if it's made it lat far the end point is being reached.

Comment: I'll try to investigate some more in the next days. Thanks for your comments.